# New files added to 7zip arhive are not protected by password

Tags: security, passwords, 7-zip, archiving

I have an archive in my onedrive for business directory that contains sensitive information that I keep password protected for extra security.  The problem is, when I add new files to the archive using the 7zip interface, they are not password protected and they can be viewed without entering the archive's password.  So now I have to extract the archive and add everything into a new arhcive in order to password protect the newly added files.

This is inconvenient because I am always adding more files that I need secured.  Unfortunately, onedrive for business does not have the personal vault so I have to resort to using archives to secure these files.  What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: "What is the solution to this problem?" - I would use something other than 7-zip since the behavior you describe is likely either a software defect or intentional behavior.  If are running Windows 10 Professional, you could in theory mount a .VHDX file from within Windows, and use BitLocker to encrypt it. Of course the file size would have to be allowed by OneDrive and NOT be blocked by the OneDrive Business GP.

Comment: Some discussion here>>>>https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/0b918e30/

Comment: What version of 7zip? Does not happen for me in 19.00. Please note that the pw protection does not get active for new files until you close and re-open the archive!